# SharePoint 2013: Word Web and Quick Parts with Lookup Values

Tags: metadata, quick-parts

I've run into an issue which may simply be a limitation of the Word Web App, however I'm not certain if this is the case, or if there is a way around this that I have overlooked.

So I have a library with a content type which represents a report, one of the columns in the content type is a lookup field to a list with client information, Name, Address etc... What I have found is that in the office client these fields are displayed properly (ie. with the Name field of the client item). But if I open the document for viewing in word web app the values which are displayed are the ID values of the lookup item, instead of the Title or other value.

Is there anyway around this so that the word web app will display the values as opposed to the ID value?

The only way that I have thought of so far is to make a copy of these columns in the report content type and either via an event receiver or workflow copy over the information from the columns in the other list. This however isn't ideal and is a fair amount of effort just to enable my users to use the word web app for these specific documents.

Any help is greatly appreciated!